# My Java program isn't changing value of variable

Tags: java, pi

I am just learning Java and decided that I would create a Pi calculator, I wrote it in Python and got it working to about 14 d.p.

The formula I'm using works by calculating the decimal part in an infinite loop and adding 3 onto it.

However now that I've brought it into Java, it doesn't see to change the the 'total' variable beyond '3.0' (this is the problem). I know that because as you can see from the code below it displays the total after every loop.

Here is the code:

```
public class divider {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declares variables
        boolean PosOrNeg = true;
        double Total = 3.0;
        long Count = 0;
        long No1 = 0;
        long No2 = 1;
        long No3 = 2;
        double Changer = 0;

        /begins loop
        do {
            // sets the value by which the total value will be changed
            No1 =+ 2;
            No2 =+ 2;
            No3 =+ 2;
            Changer = (4 / (No1 * No2 * No3));

            if (PosOrNeg == True) {
                Total = Total + Changer;
                PosOrNeg = false;
            } else {
                Total = Total - Changer;
                PosOrNeg = true;
            }

            Count += 1;
            System.out.println(Total);
        } while (Count != 31957);

        // displays total calculated and how many loops reaching that value required
        System.out.println("PI");
        System.out.println(Total);
        System.out.println(Count);
    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just a guess, but you have to use floating point division: `Changer = (4.0/(No1*No2*No3));` Note the `4.0` instead of `4`

Comment: I think @tobias_k is correct, but add a sysout of `Changer` in your loop.

Answer (score 2):

Assign variable

```
double sum = 4;
```

change

```
 No1 = +2; to  No1 +=2; or No1 = No1+2;
 No2 = +2;  to  No2 +=2; or No2 = No2+2;
 No3 = +2; to  No3 +=2; or No3 = No3+2;
```

change

```
 Changer = (4/ (No1 * No2 * No3)); to  Changer = (sum/ (No1 * No2 * No3));
```

it will work.

Comment: Since you're creating and assigning a variable you ought to be explicit: `double sum = 4.0D` rather than let integer 4 get converted to a double.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use floating point division, otherwise `Changer` will always be `0`. Python3 does this by default, but Java doesn't. Also, you mistyped `+=` as `=+`, so that `No1` through `No3` are always set to `+2` in each turn, instead of *incrementing* them by `2`.

```
        No1 += 2;                             // =+ -> +=
        No2 += 2;                             // =+ -> +=
        No3 += 2;                             // =+ -> +=
        Changer = (4.0 / (No1 * No2 * No3));  // 4  -> 4.0
```

Change those lines, and it should work. Output:

```
PI
3.141592653589793
31957
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code has error**

```
if (PosOrNeg == True) {
}
```

**it should be**

```
if (PosOrNeg == true) {
}
```

Comment: or simply `if(PosOrNeg){}`